# Please teach me how to make the template parameters of a following function

Tags: c++

I am a beginner of template. I want to make a function with template template parameters. For me, it is complicated template template parameter. And I cannot make it. Someone, please let me know how I can make it. Thank you very much.

```
class Vertex {
};

main() {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Vertex>*> vertexes_a, vertexes_b;
    CompareVector(&vertexes_a, &vertexes_b);
}

/* I made the following template parameters. But compiler cannot compile it.
 * They said template parameters invalid... It must have my stupid understanding.
 * So please ignore my template parameters and
 * please teach me how to make the template parameters. */    
template <typename Elm, template<template<Elm> class SharedPtr, typename Allocator=std::allocator<template<Elm> class SharedPtr> > class STL>
bool CompareVector(STL<std::shared_ptr<Elm>>* org, STL<std::shared_ptr<Elm>>* cmp) {
}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want this?

```
template <template <typename ...> class C, typename ...Args>
bool CompareVector(C<Args...> const * lhs, C<Args...> const * rhs)
{
    // ...
}
```

If you only want it to work for vectors:

```
template <typename T, typename A>
bool CompareVector(std::vector<T, A> const * lhs, std::vector<T, A> const * rhs);
```

If you want it to work for arbitrary template classes whose first template argument is a template class with one argument (but *why*):

```
template <template <typename ...> class C,
          template <typename> class SP,
          typename T,
          typename Args...>
bool CompareBizzare(C<SP<T>, Args...> const * lhs, /* ... */);
```

Note that none of your desired function arguments are specializations of a template that has template template parameters. The standard library does not contain any templates that take template template parameters ([for now](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4502.pdf)).

Comment: Thank you very much, Kerrek SB. I would like to specify elements of the std::vector<>  consisting of std::shared_ptr<> explicitly. Could I do it?

Comment: @mora: Yes you could!

Comment: Thank you, Kerrek SB. I will learn your example and I will try to correct my test code above. But it sounds I am doing something weird. So I may change the code later. Thank very much again.